# How do you get the following two relation from the upper central series of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$Z_2(G) \subseteq Z(G')$ and $[G, Z_2(G)] \le Z(G')$?

Comment: @hardmath Embarrassing as it is to admit, but when you have nothing to say as to what you have tried (I did try to prove this myself, but could not go very far), it's the best you could do under the circumstances, with the body containing just the problem, unless you just write the full problem in the title and repeat it again in the body, which isn't a better alternative IMO.

Comment: Your opinion counts, but my opinion is (having answered hundreds and read thousands of questions) that repeating the problem in the body, even if the words in the title get reused, is a substantial improvement for the Readers experience.  It allows you to present the facts/setup first, then ask the problem.

Comment: @hardmath I will try to fix this. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first assertion is definitely false: there is a group $G$ of order $p^ 3$, $p$ an odd prime (e.g. the group of triangular $3 \times3$ matrices over the field with $p$ elements, with $1$'s on the diagonal), with $G=Z_2(G)$ and $|G'|=p$. 
For the second: by definition $[G, Z_2(G)] \subseteq Z(G)$. But of course $[G, Z_2(G)] \subseteq [G,G]$. Hence $[G,Z_2(G)] \subseteq Z(G) \cap G' \subseteq Z(G')$.

Comment: The first inclusion is seen to be false with an easier example when $G=Q_8$. I think maybe our teacher meant to write $Z_2(G) \subseteq C_G(G')$.